# Aptoncd not reflecting all applications installed in 12.04

Tags: 12.04

Well I'm trying to back up all the applications I installed using Aptoncd however after installed launching the package, it only shows applications I installed yesterday (Ktouch & Gdebi). How do I make `Aptoncd` to recognize all application and libs installed?

BTW I was having problems with apt-get so I did a `sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get autoclean` to fix the issue successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

aptoncd uses apt cache for backuping the programs . When you run apt-get clean all . Cache is cleared . So you should download packages